# Is it possible to iterate again in a loop when catch an exception instead of continue?

Tags: java, exception, loops, try-catch, iteration

Sorry if my title is a little bit confusing.

My program is doing some web scraping and thus will catch a few SocketTimeoutException due to random network conditions. Right now when the SocketTimeoutException is caught, that particular loop is skipped, and therefore i will miss some data. I'm sure that everything will be fine when the code in the skipped loop is run again. As I'm scraping a huge amount of data ( > 1 million sets of numbers ), I don't want to record the exceptional loops and ran them again manually. Is there any way to run the same loop again when catch an exception?

```
try{
    for(){
        someCode
        ...
    }
}catch(IOException){
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't put the try/catch block *inside* the for loop?

Comment: try/catch inside the loop?

Comment: just because my program many loops in loops and everytime the IDE remind me to throw an exception i choose to handle the exception by adding more catch case to surrounding try/catch. As the number of exceptions increase, that becomes confusing. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Then you probably need to redesign your code, or at least break it up into smaller methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the `try`-`catch` inside the loop

```
for () {

  try {
    // somecode
    // ..
  } catch ( IOException ioException ) {
    // handle
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not put the exception handling inside the loop

```
for(){
     try{
         // someCode
     }catch(IOException e){
        //handle exception if necessary
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be doing this. Do try catch inside the loop.

```
for(){
    try { 
            someCode
            ...
    } catch(IOException){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I you want to redo the same loop iteration:

```
int i = 0;
int n = 15; // your n
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    try {
        // some code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        i--;
    }
}
```

But be careful of an infinite looping! You should add a MAX_TRIES management.

Answer (score 1):

This has a problem,

```
try{
    for(){
    //    someCode
        ...
    }
}catch(IOException){
  // Once exception happens your for() loop breaks !!!!!
}
```

Instead, do this...

```
 for () {

      try {
        // somecode
        // ..
      } catch ( IOException ioException ) {
        // handle(do something) here, not throwing error which will break the loop
      }

    }
```